# CSS/Javascript effect not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to implement this: https://codepen.io/arickle/details/XKjMZY
code in a single html file. When I open the file I've made, the rain effect does not display, but the toggle buttons do.
I'm not very familiar with web dev, so I'm having trouble understanding what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <style>
            html {
            height: 100%;
            }

            body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #202020, #111119);
            }

            .rain {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 2;
            }

            .rain.back-row {
            display: none;
            z-index: 1;
            bottom: 60px;
            opacity: 0.5;
            }

            body.back-row-toggle .rain.back-row {
            display: block;
            }

            .drop {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 100%;
            width: 15px;
            height: 120px;
            pointer-events: none;
            animation: drop 0.5s linear infinite;
            }

            @keyframes drop {
            0% {
                transform: translateY(0vh);
            }
            75% {
                transform: translateY(90vh);
            }
            100% {
                transform: translateY(90vh);
            }
            }

            .stem {
            width: 1px;
            height: 60%;
            margin-left: 7px;
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25));
            animation: stem 0.5s linear infinite;
            }

            @keyframes stem {
            0% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            65% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            75% {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            }

            .splat {
            width: 15px;
            height: 10px;
            border-top: 2px dotted rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
            border-radius: 50%;
            opacity: 1;
            transform: scale(0);
            animation: splat 0.5s linear infinite;
            display: none;
            }

            body.splat-toggle .splat {
            display: block;
            }

            @keyframes splat {
            0% {
                opacity: 1;
                transform: scale(0);
            }
            80% {
                opacity: 1;
                transform: scale(0);
            }
            90% {
                opacity: 0.5;
                transform: scale(1);
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 0;
                transform: scale(1.5);
            }
            }

            .toggles {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 3;
            }

            .toggle {
            position: absolute;
            left: 20px;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            line-height: 51px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            border-radius: 50%;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: background-color 0.3s;
            }

            .toggle:hover {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
            }

            .toggle:active {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
            }

            .toggle.active {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
            }

            .splat-toggle {
            top: 20px;
            }

            .back-row-toggle {
            top: 90px;
            line-height: 12px;
            padding-top: 14px;
            }

            .single-toggle {
            top: 160px;
            }

            body.single-toggle .drop {
            display: none;
            }

            body.single-toggle .drop:nth-child(10) {
            display: block;
            }
        </style>

        
</head>


<body class="back-row-toggle splat-toggle">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js">
        var makeItRain = function() {
        //clear out everything
        $('.rain').empty();
    
        var increment = 0;
        var drops = "";
        var backDrops = "";
    
        while (increment < 100) {
            //couple random numbers to use for various randomizations
            //random number between 98 and 1
            var randoHundo = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (98 - 1 + 1) + 1));
            //random number between 5 and 2
            var randoFiver = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 2 + 1) + 2));
            //increment
            increment += randoFiver;
            //add in a new raindrop with various randomizations to certain CSS properties
            drops += '<div class="drop" style="left: ' + increment + '%; bottom: ' + (randoFiver + randoFiver - 1 + 100) + '%; animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"><div class="stem" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div><div class="splat" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div></div>';
            backDrops += '<div class="drop" style="right: ' + increment + '%; bottom: ' + (randoFiver + randoFiver - 1 + 100) + '%; animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"><div class="stem" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div><div class="splat" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div></div>';
        }
    
        $('.rain.front-row').append(drops);
        $('.rain.back-row').append(backDrops);
        }
    
        $('.splat-toggle.toggle').on('click', function() {
        $('body').toggleClass('splat-toggle');
        $('.splat-toggle.toggle').toggleClass('active');
        makeItRain();
        });
    
        $('.back-row-toggle.toggle').on('click', function() {
        $('body').toggleClass('back-row-toggle');
        $('.back-row-toggle.toggle').toggleClass('active');
        makeItRain();
        });
    
        $('.single-toggle.toggle').on('click', function() {
        $('body').toggleClass('single-toggle');
        $('.single-toggle.toggle').toggleClass('active');
        makeItRain();
        });
    
        makeItRain();
    </script>
    <div class="rain front-row"></div>
    <div class="rain back-row"></div>
    <div class="toggles">
      <div class="splat-toggle toggle active">SPLAT</div>
      <div class="back-row-toggle toggle active">BACK<br>ROW</div>
      <div class="single-toggle toggle">SINGLE</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code here seems to work as expected !?

Comment: When the code is edited to separate html body, css, js,  (like you have just now, or when its in codepen) it works fine. But when it's all together in html the rain effect doesn't show...

Comment: okay, which browser do you use ? is it a file on your disk or hosted on a server ?

Comment: I'm in the latest version of chrome, the file is on my disk.

Comment: okay, it works if you fire the function onload: `window.onload=makeItRain` instead `makeItRain();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fire your function once the document is fully loaded : `window.onload=makeItRain`

```
<!-- check the Comments for more info -->
<!doctype html>

<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>  HTML5 </title>
  </head> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>var makeItRain = function() {
  //clear out everything
  $('.rain').empty();

  var increment = 0;
  var drops = "";
  var backDrops = "";

  while (increment < 100) {
    //couple random numbers to use for various randomizations
    //random number between 98 and 1
    var randoHundo = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (98 - 1 + 1) + 1));
    //random number between 5 and 2
    var randoFiver = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 2 + 1) + 2));
    //increment
    increment += randoFiver;
    //add in a new raindrop with various randomizations to certain CSS properties
    drops += '<div class="drop" style="left: ' + increment + '%; bottom: ' + (randoFiver + randoFiver - 1 + 100) + '%; animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"><div class="stem" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div><div class="splat" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div></div>';
    backDrops += '<div class="drop" style="right: ' + increment + '%; bottom: ' + (randoFiver + randoFiver - 1 + 100) + '%; animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"><div class="stem" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div><div class="splat" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div></div>';
  }

  $('.rain.front-row').append(drops);
  $('.rain.back-row').append(backDrops);
}

$('.splat-toggle.toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('splat-toggle');
  $('.splat-toggle.toggle').toggleClass('active');
  makeItRain();
});

$('.back-row-toggle.toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('back-row-toggle');
  $('.back-row-toggle.toggle').toggleClass('active');
  makeItRain();
});

$('.single-toggle.toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('single-toggle');
  $('.single-toggle.toggle').toggleClass('active');
  makeItRain();
});

window.onload=makeItRain</script>
  <style>html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #202020, #111119);
}

.rain {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.rain.back-row {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 60px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

body.back-row-toggle .rain.back-row {
  display: block;
}

.drop {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 120px;
  pointer-events: none;
  animation: drop 0.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes drop {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0vh);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(90vh);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(90vh);
  }
}

.stem {
  width: 1px;
  height: 60%;
  margin-left: 7px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25));
  animation: stem 0.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes stem {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  65% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.splat {
  width: 15px;
  height: 10px;
  border-top: 2px dotted rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: splat 0.5s linear infinite;
  display: none;
}

body.splat-toggle .splat {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes splat {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}

.toggles {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 51px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.toggle:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

.toggle:active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.toggle.active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.splat-toggle {
  top: 20px;
}

.back-row-toggle {
  top: 90px;
  line-height: 12px;
  padding-top: 14px;
}

.single-toggle {
  top: 160px;
}

body.single-toggle .drop {
  display: none;
}

body.single-toggle .drop:nth-child(10) {
  display: block;
}</style>

<body class="back-row-toggle splat-toggle">
  <div class="rain front-row"></div>
  <div class="rain back-row"></div>
  <div class="toggles">
    <div class="splat-toggle toggle active">SPLAT</div>
    <div class="back-row-toggle toggle active">BACK<br>ROW</div>
    <div class="single-toggle toggle">SINGLE</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be importing your script too soon.

The following setup will not work because the `my-div` element does not exist when the script runs.

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("my-div").innerText = "Hello to you as well.";
    </script>
    <div id="my-div">Hello</div>
</body>
```

You can fix this problem by importing the `script` at the end of the `body` (after your elements are created).

```
<body>        
    <div id="my-div">Hello</div>

    <!-- ... -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("my-div").innerText = "Hello to you as well.";
    </script>
</body>
```

You can still import jQuery in the `head` of your document. Just make sure anything that uses elements you define is imported after those elements:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>        
    <div id="my-div">Hello</div>

    <!-- ... -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#my-div').on('click', function() {
            // ...
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried importing the script at the end of the body but it still does not fix the issue..

Comment: Could you post your single-file implementation, please?